# Количество записей возвращаемое функцией COUNT()

Tags: sql, mysql

Привет есть таблица

```
id      ib      it
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
1       1       2
2       3       2
2       4       2
3       NULL    5
2       NULL    5
2       4       6
2       1       6
```

Запрос

```
 SELECT
   COUNT(*),
   COUNT(ib),
   COUNT(DISTINCT ib)
 FROM
   tbl
```

возвращает 10 7 3

Число 10 - это количество записей в таблице.

Число 3 - это число уникальных записей в колонке, отбрасывая `NULL`

А откуда берется 7?

Как получить количество записей в таблице кроме выборки где все 3 значения равны `NULL`?

Comment: Это число записей, которые не NULL. Известно, что сравнение любого значения с NULL дает в результате ложь

Comment: может,Ю вы где-то опечатались? Такие результаты должен возвращать не ваш запрос, а такой: 

` SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(id), COUNT(DISTINCT ib)
  FROM ваша_таблица`

Comment: Да действительно ошибка в данных ..Спасибо .Ваши коментарии помогли...
Тоесть я правильно понял что COUNT(id) возвращает количество значений не null,а COUNT(DISTINCT id) возращает количество неповторяемых,не null значений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А откуда берется 7?

Для представленных данных должно быть 5 - число не-NULL значений в столбце ib.

> Как получить количество записей в таблице кроме выборки где все 3 значения равны NULL?

```
select count(*) from table
where  id is null and ib is null and it is null
```

Comment: Всем благодарен.